# Should return run before or after useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

I'm following this video https://youtu.be/0ZJgIjIuY7U to learn useEffect.

According to the video the return should run first, then the useEffect itself.  However, my useEffect runs before the return.  What should be the correct sequence of execution ?

my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Use_Effect() {

    const [ val , setVal ] = useState(0)

    useEffect( () => {
        console.log('add')
        return (
            console.log('return')
        )
    }, [val] )

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={val} onChange={() => {
                setVal(pre => pre + 1)
                console.log("main window",{val})}}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

The video says I should get return -> add -> return -> add

But I'm getting add -> return -> add -> return

Thanks very much

Comment: Your code is functionally equivalent to `console.log('add'); console.log('return'); return;`. Having said that, what the video says doesn't seem right to me either. `useEffect` runs the returned function before the *next* render (and only if dependencies changed), so you'd still see `'add'` first.

Comment: yes, I saw add -> (return, add) -> (return, add) after I change it to return a function,  Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` needs to return a function which is what is ran to clean up the effect side-effects when the effect is re-ran:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function Use_Effect() {

    const [ val , setVal ] = useState(0)

    useEffect( () => {
        console.log('add')
        return () => {
            console.log('return')
        }
    }, [val] )

    return (
        <div>
            <input value={val} onChange={() => {
                setVal(pre => pre + 1)
                console.log("main window",{val})}}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

in this case `add` will be shown first and `return` will only be shown before the effect runs again.

Comment: Not when it's unmounted but when `val` changes.

Comment: @FelixKling my mistake. Updated

Comment: I got the right order now.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I wonder why return statement and a return function gives different behaviour.  Why returned statement executes immediately but not the function ?